# OLD Javascript dropdown menu not working in Chrome or IE 11

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working with a very old website and the client wants to put a bandaid on the javascript menu that isn't working in Chrome or IE 11.xxxx

I did troubleshooting in Chrome and got a lot of "Reference Error (term) not defined" messages, which I resolved. The errors went away but the menu still doesn't work.

```
<TR>
    <TD width="89" height="28"><a href="index.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image22','','images/home/new/home_on.jpg',1)"><img src="images/home/new/home_on.JPG" name="Image22" width="86" height="28" border="0"></a></TD>
    <TD width="11"><img src="images/home/new/dot_1.jpg" width="11" height="28"></TD>
    <TD width="59"><img src="images/home/new/delivery_off.jpg" width="72" height="28" name="menu0" id="menu0" onMouseOver="showMenu(event)" onMouseOut="hideMenu(event)"></TD>            
    <TD width="10"><IMG src="images/home/new/dot_3.jpg" width="10" height="28"></TD>
    <TD width="154"><img src="images/home/new/products_profitability_off.jpg" width="86" height="28" name="menu2" id="menu2" onMouseOver="showMenu(event)" onMouseOut="hideMenu(event)"></TD>
    <TD width="10"><IMG src="images/home/new/dot_2.jpg" width="10" height="28"></TD>
    <TD width="67"><img src="images/home/new/research_off.jpg" width="86" height="28" name="menu1" id="menu1" onMouseOver="showMenu(event)" onMouseOut="hideMenu(event)"></TD>
    <TD width="10"><IMG src="images/home/new/dot_4.jpg" width="10" height="28"></TD>
    <TD width="102"><img src="images/home/new/brand_strategy_off.jpg" width="75" height="28" name="menu3" id="menu3" onMouseOver="showMenu(event)" onMouseOut="hideMenu(event)"></TD>
    <TD width="10"><IMG src="images/home/new/dot_5.jpg" width="10" height="28"></TD>
    <TD width="64"><img src="images/home/new/software_off.jpg" width="94" height="28" name="menu4" id="menu4" onMouseOver="showMenu(event)" onMouseOut="hideMenu(event)"></TD>
    <TD width="9"><IMG src="images/home/dot6.jpg" width="9" height="28"></TD>
    <TD width="76"><a href="bancology.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image23','','images/home/new/bancology_on.jpg',1)"><img src="images/home/new/bancology_off.jpg" name="Image23" width="98" height="28" border="0"></a></TD>
    <TD width="10"><IMG src="images/home/dot7.jpg" width="10" height="28"></TD>
    <TD width="71"><a href="news.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image24','','images/home/new/news_on.jpg',1)"><img src="images/home/new/news_off.jpg" name="Image24" width="85" height="28" border="0"></a></TD>
  </TR>
```

Comment: Aaaah good ol' `MM_veryLongMethodNames` - it's been a while! These sort of menus were created with Macromedia Dreamweaver, and it's no surprise they don't work with modern browsers - It was written when IE6 was modern!

Comment: Why didn't you post the JavaScript?

Comment: Honestly I didn't know what to post.  The file references three .js files - then in the script folder there are .js files for browsers dating back to netscape